# How to confirm user created by create_user in flask security mongoengine app?

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, mongoengine, flask-security

I have a python flask app using **mongoengine** and **flask-security** built up from the examples to expose all of the confirmation, registration, tracking, and recovery functionality.

Everything works except that a user created imperatively in the code using:

```
MongoEngineUserDatastore.create_user(...)
```

cannot login. That is, when you try to login with this user, you get an error message:

```
"Email requires confirmation"
```

Since the email with a hashed URL has not been sent, there is no way to confirm. Is there a parameter I can pass somewhere to confirm this user on creation or set the confirmed flag somewhere?

[Here](https://gist.github.com/davidthewatson/327776905ef30815c138)'s my code:

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured it out by confirming a newly registered user and examining mongodb to see what fields were added. Turns out that the required field for confirmation is confirmed_at, which must have a datetime so:

```
import datetime

# Create a user to test with
@app.before_first_request
def create_user():
    user_datastore.create_user(
        email='me@mydomain.com',
        password=utils.encrypt_password('password'),
        confirmed_at=datetime.datetime.now())
```

I've updated the gist here:

https://gist.github.com/davidthewatson/327776905ef30815c138

Comment: Cool - please mark as answered and that will help other users, with similar issues.

Comment: I'd love to mark it as answered. Unfortunately, SO doesn't allow me to mark it answered for two days for reasons that are beyond me.

Answer (score 1):

When you create your test user you need to make them active eg:

```
@app.before_first_request
def create_user():
    user_datastore.create_user(
        email='me@mydomain.com', 
        password=utils.encrypt_password('password'),
        active=True)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Ross. Unfortunately, that didn't work. It did set the active flag true which can be seen in this mongo query result: > db.user.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("513755fd0d3085357eef0fff"), "_types" : [ "User" ], "roles" : [ ], "_cls" : "User", "active" : true, "password" : "$2a$12$aeT/0Nb9mtQ/hAPAIwoG7.9Q27P9ytz/guDXhE7KbpksskwRZeXCC", "email" : "me@mydomain.com" }
but the login still fails with "Email requires confirmation".

Comment: The active flag is for flask-login.